# Cleanly setting ACLs

Tags: powershell

So this is my full script that I've been working on. My plan is to Create New, Folder, Create AD Group FS-TESTSHARE-R, Create AD Group FS-TESTSHARE-RW, Apply Both groups to the new share folder, Set Full Read permissions to FS-TESTSHARE-R, Set Full Read/Rights permissions to FS-TESTSHARE-RW, and Set full access permissions to Domain Admins and local Administrators.

I'm Pretty sure I have all of the syntax correct now (thanks to some awesome assistance I've received here), but I was hoping for some clarification on setting ACLs.

At the bottom I've redone how I was attempting to get, create, and set the ACLs Thanks to @themadtechnician), but I was curious as to if I've got all syntax correct or if I should create the set for each of the $objUser instead of putting them all in parentheses (is this the cleanest way to do this)...

```
$Parent = read-host -prompt "Enter full parent path that will contain the new folder (ie. \\eccofs01\Groups\ECCO IT\)"
$Name = read-host -prompt "Enter New Folder Name."
$Path = "$($parent)$($Name)"
$Location = read-host -prompt "Enter the AD Security Group Location (i.e. Global, Americas, Europe, Asia Pacific)"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Create Security Groups
$GroupParams1= @{
    'Name' = "FS-$NAME-RW" 
    'SamAccountName' = "FS-$NAME-RW" 
    'GroupCategory' = "Security"
    'GroupScope' = "Global"
    'DisplayName' = "$NAME Read-Write Access"
    'Path' = "CN=$LOCATION,CN=SECURITY GROUPS,CN=FILE SHARE GROUPS,DC=ESG,DC=INTL"
    'Description' = "Members of this group have read-write access to $Path."
}

New-ADGroup @GroupParams1

$GroupParams2= @{
    'Name' = "FS-$NAME-R" 
    'SamAccountName' = "FS-$NAME-R" 
    'GroupCategory' = "Security"
    'GroupScope' = "Global"
    'DisplayName' = "$NAME Read-Write Access"
    'Path' = "CN=$LOCATION,CN=SECURITY GROUPS,CN=FILE SHARE GROUPS,DC=ESG,DC=INTL"
    'Description' = "Members of this group have read access to $Path"
}

New-ADGroup @GroupParams2

# Create New Folder
New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory


#Set Full Control Permissions
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Administrators","esg.intl\Domain Admins","esg.intl\FS-$NAME-RW") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL $Path

$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL $Path $objACL


#Set Read and Execute Permissions
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("esg.intl\FS-$NAME-R") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL $Path

$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL $Path $objACL
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To streamline the permission handling you may want to wrap ACE creation in a function and set the ACL just once at after all ACEs were added:

```
function New-Ace {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [Security.Principal.NTAccount]$Account,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
    [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$Permissions = 'ReadAndExecute',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]$InheritanceFlags = 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
    [Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]$PropagationFlags = 'None',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
    [Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]$Type = 'Allow'
  )

  New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $Account, $Permissions, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $Type
  )
}

$domain = 'DOMAIN'

$acl = Get-Acl $path

'Administrators', "$domain\Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object {
  $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $_ 'FullControl'))
}
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace "$domain\FS-$NAME-RW" 'Modify'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace "$domain\FS-$NAME-R" 'ReadAndExecute'))

Set-Acl $path $acl
```

Other improvements might include determining the administrators and domain admins group names independent of the system's locale by their [well-known SIDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330), e.g.:

```
$administrators = ([wmi]"Win32_Sid.Sid='S-1-5-32-544'").AccountName

$domain_admins  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Account |
                  Where-Object { $_.SID -like '*-512' } |
                  Select-Object -Expand Caption
```

Another thing you could do is map names to permissions like this:

```
$permissions = @{
  'Administrators'        = 'FullControl'
  "$domain\Domain Admins" = 'FullControl'
  "$domain\FS-$NAME-RW"   = 'Modify'
  "$domain\FS-$NAME-R"    = 'ReadAndExecute'
}
```

and use the hashtable as input for the ACE creation:

```
$permissions.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $_ $permissions[$_]))
}
```

Of course this implies that all ACEs have the same type and flags, otherwise you'd have to use a more elaborate data structure.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. I'm really new to this and that helps a ton!

Comment: If I was to use the SID method would this be the correct format:

Comment: Just realized that I'm unable to insert code in the comments. I've added an update to my primary post. Does that look correct?

Comment: @ShaneJohnson if you want an updated version of your code peer reviewed, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Gotchya, sorry about that. I searched and found people saying to add an update to the original post to add the full code block.

Comment: Well if Ansgar is here the PowerShell tag is all the better for it.

Comment: Quick question on how to change the inheritence and propagation flags for FS-$NAME-R and RW: How would I add that to the string `$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace "$domain\FS-$NAME-RW" 'Modify'))` ?  I tried quite a few ways and I couldn't get it to work. I was assuming that since 'Modify' changed the $permission flag that adding the other items after it in the same manner would allow those to be changed as well. I only wanted to change those two flags for the R and RW security groups, but everything else stays the same.

Comment: @ShaneJohnson Adding inheritance and propagation flags to the parameter list should work. If it doesn't work for you please post a question on StackOverflow showing the full code that didn't work and any error it produced.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... I did add the question quite a few days ago without any answers... [Here is the link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778961/trying-to-prevent-a-security-group-from-applying-to-other-folders-files)

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy last week, so I've been neglecting SO. I'll look into it tonight if I find the time.